# Joining QlikView tables resorts in unwanted repeated entries

Tags: qlikview

I have 2 .csv with ';' separated files i loaded into Qlikview.

first file contains:

> ID | date/time | Price | Postalcode

the second contains

> ID | Postalcode | City | Region

I've first did an extract to a .qvd file and in the .qvw i added the following code:

```
Customerpostalcode:
LOAD %key_CustomerId,
     TimeDate,  
     Price, 
     %key_postalcode
FROM
[$(vExtract)Customerpostalcodes.qvd]
(qvd);

Postcodes:
LEFT JOIN (Customerpostalcodes)
LOAD %key_postalcodeID,
     %key_postalcode, 
     City, 
     Region
FROM
[$(vExtract)Postalcodes.qvd]
(qvd);
```

Now here in Belgium you have multiple cities for one postal code

for example if postal code is "9700" then i have 15 cities but if the price for postal code 9700 is €50 than i got 15 times €50. How can i tell Qlikview to only count and sum this price one time each postal code?

Thx

Comment: I did not get the problem. You can add a listbox to display the 'postal code' and select there the '9700'. And you have e.g. a text field that displays sum(Price) then you get 750€, because the were 15 entries with 50€ each. Now add a listbox to display the 'City' now you can filter on the selectable 15 cities. If I got you wrong please tell us a litte bit more.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have a many-to-many relationship in your `Postcodes` table so JOINing this into the first table will explode the table with the repeated entries.

Perhaps you need to try and figure out a way of expanding your source data for `Customerpostalcode` so that the table also contains more address information for the customer (for example by including `City`). This way you could then join the tables on both `%key_postalcode` and `City` which would then result in hopefully single matches which would then solve your issue.